# Match only first occurrence

Tags: regex

This is my regex `^(\d.+(?:\.\d+))`

and this is my string

> 13.5 common area expenses. the term "common area expenses", as used in this lease, shall mean all costs and expenses, 12.5 by landlord in (a) operating, managing, policing, insuring, repairing, maintaining and replacing the shopping center.

and as output I want only first occurrence i.e `13.5` **not** `12.5`. The format should be like `1.` or `1.2.1`

Comment: [`^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/y3eS7W/2) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a comment but it was wrong. For `1.` or `1.1.1` to match you should make one `\d+\.` mandatory and a second one `\d+\.` optional (`*` quantifier to repeat if possible):

```
^\d+\.(?:\d+\.?)*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/5skOhY/1)

Note that dot in second group is optional. You may remove `^` if match is not necessarily at beginning of input.